# Regex for one or more words separated by spaces

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regex where i have one or more words (possibly should cover alpha numeric also) separated by spaces (one or more spaces)

1. " Test This stuff "
2. " Test this "
3. " Test "

Above are some examples of it

I wrote a regex to see what is repeating for #1

```
\s*[a-zA-Z]*\s*[a-zA-Z]*\s*[a-zA-Z]*\s*
```

so i wanted to do something like `{3}` for repeating section.

But it does not seem to work.. I cant believe it is this difficult.

```
(\s*[a-zA-Z]*){3}
```

Comment: What language or utility are you doing this in?

Comment: I think you have to change `*` to `+`. So you get `(\s+[a-zA-Z]+){3}`

Comment: I would use something like [this](http://regex101.com/r/oC4aB6/1) `(?:\s*[a-zA-Z]+){1,3}`

Comment: `{3}` means _exactly_ 3 repetitions, so it will only work for #1. If you want 1-3 words, it should be `{1,3}`.

Comment: if you want exact three words or 1 to three words then why you put this "Regex for one or more words separated by spaces" in the title?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

If you do not care just how many words you have, this would work:

```
[\w\s]+
```

`\w` is any alphanumeric. Replace it with `a-zA-Z` if you need only letters.

Comment: 0001 :: Test This Stuff :: #### PASS =====> This is the text that I am writing a regex for? I wrote a regex here which does not seem to work - i want to write a generic one instead of a specific one  "if re.search('\d\d\d\d\s::\s[[a-zA-Z]\s]+::\s\#\#\#\#\s[A-Z]*', aline):"

Comment: The number of words can vary..which is why I want a generic one. "Test This Stuff" or "Test" or "Test Stuff".. something like that.

Comment: This regex should work for your purpose. However, your regex engine may need to wrap it in `^$` for your tests to pass, like this: `^[\w\s]+$`

Comment: But the ^ would match the very beginning of the line.. wouldnt it?

Comment: Yes, `^` means that it must start from the beginning - use it if you need to check that whole string contains only words with spaces and nothing else. Check this [fiddle.re link](http://fiddle.re/awq7z) (click on Java test)

Comment: "if re.search('\d\d\d\d\s::\s[[a-zA-Z]\s]+::\s\#\#\#\#\s[A-Z]*', aline):" --- this dosent work for me!!?!

Comment: You can't use `[[a-zA-Z]\s]` - this is invalid syntax. Use `[a-zA-Z\s]`

Comment: MVP - that did not work either "if re.search('\d\d\d\d\s::\s[a-zA-Z\s]+::\s\#\#\#\#\s[A-Z]*', aline)"

Comment: You should provide more information in your question: what is your input and what is your expected output - right now we can only guess on what is your goal, because you are not telling whole story

Comment: Duh.. i was not grouping in the script correctly.. Thanks that's the answer!

Comment: be careful, because `[\w]` will catch `\n` as well.

Comment: @Javix: `[\w]` will not catch newline. `\s` will, you can replace it with just literal space.

Comment: @mvp Yep, my bad, exactly.

Comment: Thanks, best way for me

Answer (score 13):

I think you need something like this,

```
^\s*[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:\s+[A-Za-z0-9]+)*\s*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fM7uA5/3)

OR

```
^(?:\s+[A-Za-z0-9]+)+\s+$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fM7uA5/4)

Comment: I like your answer the most because it doesn't match empty strings, such as, `'                '` (ie, a bunch of spaces, apostrophes not included, just for visualization). Right now it does validate for things like: `'       this is a string with spaces before'`, but this case could be invalidated by removing the `\s` at the beginning of the pattern (although I'm keeping it as it's useful). I was attempting my own solution to this, but was getting stuck--your use of the non-capturing group = . I added some other special characters for my own usage. Thanks for the helpful contribution!