# I need a regular expression for "at least one word"

Tags: regex

I'm new here, and I'm working on a student project

I need a regular expression for "at least one word"

Should it be \w+ ??

Comment: A similar question has been asked before :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25131949/regex-for-one-or-more-words-separated-by-spaces

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex for one or more words separated by spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25131949/regex-for-one-or-more-words-separated-by-spaces)

Answer (score 0):

\w stands for “word character”. It always matches the ASCII characters [A-Za-z0-9_]

https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html

So [A-Za-z]+ should probably be better. Note that it will be ok for word from only one letter.